# what orm BLToolkit is not more popular?

Tags: .net, orm, frameworks, bltoolkit

i search to work with data accces orm faster and speed for fetch and implementation
I came across BLToolKit in the **OrmBattle** http://www.ormbattle.net/, which seems absolutely amazing in terms of performance, speed ,maintainability, and flexibility.
But is not very known ?is that it's true comparison in http://www.ormbattle.net/ 
if someone have an idea with BLToolkit, can help me  ?
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why isn't BLToolkit more popular?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227267/why-isnt-bltoolkit-more-popular)

Answer (score 5):

That is also how I find about the BLToolkit almost a year ago. Since then I use it in all of my projects of which the two of them are large commercial projects. I would higly recomend it to everyone. Just keep in mind that you work directly with database when using the BLToolkit, which means that every select, insert, update or delete command is immediatly executed on the server.

Answer (score 5):

I've been addicted to BLToolkit for 3 years now :(

The problem with BLToolkit is that it has the right level of abstraction

So you still have to think about your DB, but you don't have to write real SQL in strings (As in Dapper) because you have a great extensible Linq Provider.

And you don't have entity tracking and lazy loading which usually cause the real performance problems (N + 1 Selects) (As in Nhibernate/EF)

Be sure to out check this page http://bltoolkit.net/Doc.Linq.ashx

Answer (score 4):

this is the philosophical question, and as others has no answer (or not only one answer).

BLT is awesome, but it is mostly undocumented (unit tests and self documenting code approach this is mostly only documentstion), but if you will use it - you will love it :)

Answer (score 2):

I've got nothing to say about BLToolkit but...

if you're looking for a lightweight ORM which is very (very) fast, have a look at [Dapper-dot-net](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/). Its usage is very simple and intiuitive and you can easy add it to your projects with `NuGet` or simple add the one required file.

If you're scrolling down to the `Performance`, you'll also have a direct compare between `Dapper` and `BLToolkit`

Comment: Yes if you are looking for speed choose Dapper, If you are looking for speed AND productivity choose BLToolkit

Comment: Instead of BLToolkit Id rather suggest using PetaPoco for productivity. Has a nice query builder and is extremely fast.

Answer (score 2):

It is not popular because the author does not invest in popularization.

I have worked with Linq2Sql, NHybernate, EF, have tried a couple of commercial ORM frameworks and code-generation DALs.

In my oppinion BLT is the best. Why? Because it gives you just right level of abstraction. It supports Linq selects/updates/inserts/deletes and no entity tracking boolshit.

Answer (score 1):

BLToolkit is not a feature rich ORM like NHibernate (and to a lesser extent Entity Framework).  The feature rich ORMs are much more popular.

ORMBattle does not have a great reputation because it was started by one of the featured vendors (i.e. rampant complaints of bias) and NHibernate and LLBLGen, two of the more popular .NET ORMs, were not represented properly.